# Python pillow library screenshot

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Why can I use `ImageGrab.grab(300,200,400,150)` but not this: `ImageGrab.grab(bbox)`?

Code and error message:

```
def wl(wx,wy):
    local = win32gui.GetWindowRect(wds)
    dx = wx+local[0]
    dy = wy+local[1]
    return (dx,dy)
def wlw (x,y,z,a):
    return wl(x,y)+wl(z,a)
bbox = wlw(300,200,400,150)
pic = ImageGrab.grab(bbox)
pic.save(r'C:\Users\shang\Desktop\test.jpg')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/shang/PycharmProjects/test/First.py", line 90, in <module>
    pic.save(r'C:\Users\shang\Desktop\test.jpg')
  File "C:\Users\shang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2088, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "C:\Users\shang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PIL\JpegImagePlugin.py", line 779, in _save
    ImageFile._save(im, fp, [("jpeg", (0, 0) + im.size, 0, rawmode)], bufsize)
  File "C:\Users\shang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 525, in _save
    e.setimage(im.im, b)
SystemError: tile cannot extend outside image

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Well, what's the value of `bbox`?  It's being calculated based on information we can't see.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot run the program as I do not have `wds` nor `win32gui` that I do not want to install. Please note that bbox is a tuple with 4 values while ImageGrab.grab takes 4 arguments, so try `ImageGrab.grab(*bbox)` where the tuple is expanded to 4 variables. So:

```
def wl(wx, wy):
    local = win32gui.GetWindowRect(wds)
    dx = wx + local[0]
    dy = wy + local[1]
    return (dx,dy)


def wlw (x, y, z, a):
    return wl(x, y) + wl(z, a)


bbox = wlw(300, 200, 400, 150)
pic = ImageGrab.grab(*bbox)

pic.save('C:\Users\shang\Desktop\test.jpg')
```

Some advice. Try to follow the PEP8 guidelines using spaces and white lines to make the code more readable (like space after comma's and two lines between functions).
Make names more descriptive, what is function `wl` and `wlw`? What is `local`, `z`, `a`? When a function describe what the functions does like `get_local_window` or something like that. 
Is it really necessary to use two functions `wl` and `wlw`, can `wl` not just be part of `wlw`?